# difference between Video Capture rate , Frame Rate and Refresh Rate in video processing

Tags: video-adapters, video-editing, video-capture, video-game-console

What exactly difference between Video Capture rate, Frame Rate and Refresh Rate in video processing ?
Can we change FPS of CPU graphics ie. rate of Frame per second or not? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before explaining what's **Video Capture rate**, let's read what's **Refresh Rate** and **Frame Rate**.

## Refresh rate:

Refresh rate represents how many times the actual TV, video display, or projected **screen image is completely reconstructed every second**. The idea is that the **more times the screen is "refreshed" every second, the smoother the image is** in terms of motion rendering and flicker reduction.

In other words, the image looks better the faster the screen can refresh itself. **Refresh rates** of televisions and other types of video displayed are measured in "Hz" (Hertz). For example, a television with a 60hz refresh rate represents a complete reconstruction of the screen image 60 times every second.

As a result, this also means that each video frame (in a 30 frame per second signal) is repeated twice every 60th of a second. By looking at the math, one can easily figure out how other frame rates relate to other refresh rates.

## Frame rate:

Remember those cool little flip books where a pad of paper had an image on every page, and when you flipped through the pages quickly, the image would appear to animate and move? This is essentially how video works. Whether digital or old-school film, **video is a series of still images** that, when viewed in order at a certain speed, give the appearance of motion.

https://techsmith-13.wistia.com/medias/bzujp1kl5e?embedType=async&videoFoam=true&videoWidth=640

**Frame rate** is the speed at which those images are shown, or how fast you “flip” through the book and it’s usually expressed as “frames per second,” or FPS. **Each image represents a frame**, so if a video is captured and played back at 24fps, that means each second of video shows 24 distinct still images. **The speed at which they’re shown tricks your brain into perceiving smooth motion**.

## Video Capture rate:

**Video Capture rate** is just on how many FPS (**Frames Per Second**) the video will be **captured/recorded**. As we read above, with more FPS the video stay smoother, and with less FPS, it stays more "laggy".

Now let's talk about

## GPU Frame rate:

**FPS can easily change** while you're using the computer. **Heavy tasks** like playing games can **decrease your Frame Rate**, while just using your Browser it's almost not going to change your Frame Rate (**FPS**).

Higher resolutions decrease Frame Rate (**FPS**), since the image to load is heavier.

There are many ways of **increasing your FPS**, I suggest [this](http://blog.logicalincrements.com/2014/06/frames-per-second-5-simple-tips-to-boost-your-fps/) website.

## Related:

> How is the frame capture rate and Refresh rate depends upon each other?

Remember that **FPS is how many frames your computer is producing or drawing**, while the **refresh rate is how many times the monitor is refreshing the image** on the screen. The refresh rate (**Hz**) of your monitor does not affect the frame rate (**FPS**) your **GPU** will be outputting. However, if your **FPS** is higher than your refresh rate, your display will not be able to display all of the frames your computer is producing, so although the refresh rate doesn’t technically limit the frame rate, it does effectively set a cap.

> If I have 60Hz monitor then how much fps Video Capture card needed so that I don't want to loose any frame while capturing through video?

As we read above, the refresh rate (**Hz**) doesn't really matter if we're speaking about frame rate (**FPS**), so just record your video at **60 FPS** and it's all set.

Sources: https://www.lifewire.com/video-frame-vs-screen-refresh-rate-1847855, https://www.techsmith.com/blog/frame-rate-beginners-guide/, https://www.avadirect.com/blog/frame-rate-fps-vs-hz-refresh-rate/ and my knowledge.

I hope this satisfies your doubts.

Brhaka

Comment: Thank You Brhaka , It's very helpful content I got it. I would like to have One more query that In getting confused to one problem which is as here :- If I have 60Hz monitor then how much fps Video Capture card needed so that I don't want to loose any frame while capturing through video having Maximum FPS as 60 fps.

Comment: I would Like to sum up my query as :- How is the frame capture rate and Refresh rate depends upon each other? Is there any way like any mathematical proof that Make us understand much more clear way. Kindly help me by the helpful suggestion. Once again thank you for the suggestion.